# Writing a Parser for a programming language: Output

Tags: c++, parsing, output, lexer

I'm trying to write a simple interpreted programming language in C++. I've read that a lot of people use tools such Lex/Flex Bison to avoid "reinventing the wheel", but since my goal is to understand how these little beasts work improving my knowledge, i've decided to write the Lexer and the Parser from scratch. At the moment i'm working on the parser (the lexer is complete) and i was asking myself what should be its output. A tree? A linear vector of statements with a "depth" or "shift" parameter? How should i manage loops and if statements? Should i replace them with invisible goto statements?

Comment: That's a very open ended question. You don't say who you're writing this for: are you writing a compiler or an interpreted language, or are you writing a generic code generator? Of course, if you are writing this as the parser for your own programming language, then you kind of need to decide how your compiler/virtual machine is going to work and then that's the output you need to produce.

Comment: @kfsone The design of a *parser* is impacted by a many things, but the details of the target platform and implementation strategy are not among them in my experience. Could you give an example of how the *parser's* output is affected by how the target VM works?

Comment: @delnan Certainly - if the VM is a stand-alone binary which processes compiled files, and you are going to the effort of hand-rolling a compiler, then I would assume that what you return from your parser would be somewhat shaped by that decision vs what you would return if you were writing it as an embedded parser running at/within the VM. If you were, instead, intending to generate code for a secondary compiler to process, you might choose a different approach.

Comment: Well, it's a parser for my own interpreted programming language (a simple one). Starting from the interpreter seems a good advice, but the problem is the same: there are a lot of ways to make it work and i can't figure out the best

Comment: @napco See delnan's answer then.

Comment: @kfsone You assume, but you're wrong. The front end of a compiler is as independent as possible of the target architecture.

Comment: @kfsone - Sounds like perhaps you haven't actually written a parser front end? I've never had platform dependent details in my parsers.

Comment: See my answer where I explain why I think implementing a VM at the same time as a language is a bad idea. Both are huge undertakings. Don't burnout. There is a reason the old "Dragon Book" has a Dragon on the front and a knight with a sword. This type of project is one of the true dragons in Computer Science. Fight smaller dragons one at the time.

Comment: @mrjoltcola Infact, I've been writing interpreters and compilers since the mid 80s, and I self-bootstrapped like the OP. He's been quite specific about why he's trying to do this, and none of the answers have actually been particularly helpful in the vein/spirit he is learning. Returning an AST is a convention/norm, and it has its merits, but for someone who is working stepping their way thru the process, going straight from "ok I've tokenized and parsed" to "I have an AST" leaves a learning chasm and may add more early-stage complexity than necessary.

Comment: @kfsone - You make a good point, so I didn't downvote your earlier posts, but they led me to believe differently. I still say you should separate the front-end from the platform and write or choose the platform for the language, and not vice-versa.

Comment: @kfsone I've been studying compilers since 1972, and writing compilers since 1976, and separation of the parser from the target architecture was one of the first things I was taught in Compiler Construction 201 and again at Frank deRemer's summer school. It's called the MxN problem in the literature, and this is the solution. gcc is a good example: several parsers, several back ends, *voila!* M parsers for N architectures without having to write M*N different compilers. I disagree with your comment about unhelpful answers too.

Comment: @kfsone - Don't you feel that you are more prepared to learn/absorb/reimplement a parser / lexer once you had learn (from experience) the way the traditional tools work?

Comment: @EJP I think we're having a clash of terminology, but also, as you point out, you're talking about compiler construction 201 as opposed to 101 :). I never studied compiler construction, I'm self-taught. I built my first in 1984 aged 13, a MUD language - I don't mean a MUD parser, I mean a parser/parser-generator for writing MUDs which built the game and generated the in-game parser. I subsequently passed the compiler class at college without attending a class or reading any of the books. The OP seems like he wants to work thru the problem for himself.

Comment: @kfsone: Though I attended Compiler Construction in school, I also learned _more_ from writing a MUD (MUD++). Small world. I think we compiler writers also tend to be the ones that do self-teach. But I have to agree with EJP. I think there is no justification for skipping an AST and suggesting to do so is advice that will get OP into a mess. After all, interpreters can simply use the AST and be done, voila, we have our runtime engine. That is what Perl and Python and other scripting languages do.

Comment: @kfsone You made an assertion and it was incorrect. It's still incorrect, for the reasons I've given. Much of your comment seems to be addressed to somebody else.

Comment: >>"answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise" --   How is that? This is a computer science question with years of research and fact and literature behind it.

Comment: I disagree with putting the OP's question on hold and I question the qualifications of those who voted to put it on hold, relative to this subject matter. This is a highly specialized, difficult, but mature field of computer science. Stack Overflow needs less janitors and more experts and people passionate about topics. 2 more votes needed to reopen the question.

Answer (score 8):

A parser should almost always output an [AST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree). An AST is simply, in the broadest sense, a tree representation of the syntactical structure of the program. A Function becomes an AST node containing the AST of the function body. An `if` becomes an AST node containing the AST of the condition and the body. A use of an operator becomes an AST node containing the AST of each operand. Integer literals, variable names, and so on become leaf AST nodes. Operator precedence and such is implicit in the relationship of the nodes: Both `1 * 2 + 3` and `(1 * 2) + 3` are represented as `Add(Mul(Int(1), Int(2)), Int(3))`.

Many details of what's in the AST depend on your language (obviously) and what you want to do with the tree. If you want to analyze and transform the program (i.e. split out altered source code at the end), you might preserve comments. If you want detailed error messages, you might add source locations (as in, this integer literal was on line 5 column 12).

A compiler will proceed to turn the AST into a different format (e.g. a linear IR with `goto`s, or data flow graphs). Going through the AST is still a good idea, because a well-designed AST has a good balance of being syntax-oriented but only storing what's important for *understanding* the program. The parser can focus on parsing while the later transformations are protected from irrelevant details such as the amount of white space and operator precedence. Note that such a "compiler" might also output bytecode that's later interpreted (the reference implementation of Python does this).

A relatively pure interpreter might instead interpret the AST. Much has been written about this; it is about the easiest way to execute the parser's output. This strategy benefits from the AST in much the same way as a compiler; in particular most interpretation is simply top-down traversal of the AST.

Comment: Well, my token struct is holding information about its position inside the source code, so i can retrieve it basically from both the parser and the interpreter. I'll give a look to AST, thanks

Answer (score 2):

The formal and most properly correct answer is going to be that you should return an Abstract Syntax Tree. But that is simultaneously the tip of an iceberg and no answer at all.

An AST is simply a structure of nodes describing the parse; a visualization of the paths your parse took thru the token/state machine.

Each node represents a path or description. For example, you would have nodes which represents language statements, nodes which represent compiler directives and nodes which represent data.

Consider a node which describes a variable, and lets say your language supports variables of int and string and the notion of "const". You may well choose to make the type a direct property of the Variable node struct/class, but typically in an AST you make properties - like constness - a "mutator", which is itself some form of node linked to the Variable node.

You could implement the C++ concept of "scope" by having locally-scoped variables as mutations of a BlockStatement node; the constraints of a "Loop" node (for, do, while, etc) as mutators.

When you closely tie your parser/tokenizer to your language implementation, it can become a nightmare making even small changes.

While this is true, if you actually want to understand how these things work, it is worth going through at least one first implementation where you begin to implement your runtime system (vm, interpreter, etc) and have your parser target it directly. (The alternative is, e.g., to buy a copy of the "Dragon Book" and read how it's supposed to be done, but it sounds like you are actually wanting to have the full understanding that comes from having worked thru the problem yourself).

The trouble with being *told* to return an AST is that an AST actually needs a form of parsing.

```
struct Node
{
    enum class Type {
        Variable,
        Condition,
        Statement,
        Mutator,
    };

    Node*  m_parent;
    Node*  m_next;
    Node*  m_child;
    Type   m_type;
    string m_file;
    size_t m_lineNo;

};

struct VariableMutatorNode : public Node
{
    enum class Mutation {
        Const
    };
    Mutation m_mutation;
    // ...
};

struct VariableNode
{
    VariableMutatorNode* m_mutators;

    // ...
};

Node* ast;  // Top level node in the AST.
```

This sort of AST is probably OK for a compiler that is independent of its runtime, but you'd need to tighten it up a lot for a complex, performance sensitive language down the (at which point there is less 'A' in 'AST').

The way you walk this tree is to start with the first node of 'ast' and act acording to it. If you're writing in C++, you can do this by attaching behaviors to each node type. But again, that's not so "abstract", is it?

Alternatively, you have to write something which works its way thru the tree.

```
switch (node->m_type) {
    case Node::Type::Variable:
        declareVariable(node);
        break;
    case Node::Type::Condition:
        evaluate(node);
        break;
    case Node::Type::Statement:
        execute(node);
        break;
}
```

And as you write this, you'll find yourself thinking "wait, why didn't the parser do this for me?" because processing an AST often feels a lot like you did a crap job of implementing the AST :)

There are times when you can skip the AST and go straight to some form of final representation, and (rare) times when that is desirable; then there are times when you *could* go straight to some form of final representation but now you have to change the language and that decision will cost you a lot of reimplementation and headaches.

This is also generally the meat of building your compiler - the lexer and parser are generally the lesser parts of such an under taking. Working with the abstract/post-parse representation is a much more significant part of the work.

That's why people often go straight to flex/bison or antlr or some such.

And if that's what you want to do, looking at .NET or LLVM/Clang can be a good option, but you can also fairly easily bootstrap yourself with something like this: http://gnuu.org/2009/09/18/writing-your-own-toy-compiler/4/

Best of luck :)

Comment: Fantastic explanation, and code spinet. I build the AST but I was lost as to what I need to loop through. Your switch statement provides the answer (the types).

Answer (score 1):

I would build a tree of statements. After that, yes the goto statements are how the majority of it works (jumps and calls). Are you translating to a low level like assembly?

Comment: no, i'll write an interpreter in C++ and i'll play with it afterwards, focusing on its C++ API (extending it etc...). I think i'll try with goto statements then, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The output of the parser should be an abstract syntax tree, unless you know enough about writing compilers to directly produce byte-code, if that's your target language. It can be done in one pass but you need to know what you're doing. The AST expresses loops and ifs directly: you're not concerned with translating them yet. That comes under code generation.

Comment: Parse tree or AST? The definitions I'm used to is that a parse tree contains information about how exactly the parser walked through the grammar in its whole redundant glory, with lots of intermediate nodes that exist for disambiguation. That seems like a rather unfriendly format for the later stages.

Comment: What you're describing sounds more like the grammar itself. But to be clear I do mean an AST.

Comment: Yeah, a parse tree after the definition I learned is very closely related to the grammar. Basically a trace of how you'd derive the input string from the grammar.

Answer (score 1):

People don't use lex/yacc to avoid re-inventing the wheel, the use it to build a more robust compiler prototype more quickly, with less effort, and to focus on the language, and avoid getting bogged down in other details. From personal experience with several VM projects, compilers and assemblers, I suggest if you want to learn how to build a language, do just that -- focus on building a language (first).

**Don't** get distracted with:

1. Writing your own VM or runtime
2. Writing your own parser generator
3. Writing your own intermediate language or assembler

You can do these later.

This is a common thing I see when a bright young computer scientist first catches the "language fever" (and its good thing to catch), but you need to be careful and focus your energy on the one thing you want to do well, and make use of other robust, mature technologies like parser generators, lexers, and runtime platforms. You can always circle back later, when you have slain the compiler dragon first.

Just spend your energy learning how a LALR grammar works, write your language grammar in Bison or Yacc++ if you can still find it, don't get distracted by people who say you should be using ANTLR or whatever else, that isn't the goal early on. Early on, you need to focus on crafting your language, removing ambiguities, creating a **proper AST** (maybe the most important skillset), semantic checking, symbol resolution, type resolution, type inference, implicit casting, tree rewriting, and of course, end program generation. There is enough to be done making a proper language that you don't need to be learning multiple other areas of research that some people spend their whole careers mastering.

I recommend you target an existing runtime like the CLR (.NET). It is one of the best runtimes for crafting a hobby language. Get your project off the ground using a textual output to IL, and assemble with ilasm. ilasm is relatively easy to debug, assuming you put some time into learning it. Once you get a prototype going, you can then start thinking about other things like an alternate output to your own interpreter, in case you have language features that are too dynamic for the CLR (then look at the DLR). The main point here is that CLR provides a good intermediate representation to output to. Don't listen to anyone that tells you you should be directly outputting bytecode. Text is king for learning in the early stages and allows you to plug and play with different languages / tools. A good book is by the author John Gough, titled ***Compiling for the .NET Common Language Runtime (CLR)*** and he takes you through the implementation of the Gardens Point Pascal Compiler, but it isn't a book about Pascal, it is a book about how to build a real compiler on the CLR. It will answer many of your questions on implementing loops and other high level constructs.

Related to this, a great tool for learning is to use Visual Studio and ildasm (the disassembler) and .NET Reflector. All available for free. You can write small code samples, compile them, then disassemble them to see how they map to a stack based IL.

If you aren't interested in the CLR for whatever reason, there are other options out there. You will probably run across llvm, Mono, NekoVM, and Parrot (all good things to learn) in your searches. I was an original Parrot VM / Perl 6 developer, and wrote the Perl Intermediate Representation language and imcc compiler (which is quite a terrible piece of code I might add) and the first prototype Perl 6 compiler. I suggest you stay away from Parrot and stick with something easier like .NET CLR, you'll get much further. If, however, you want to build a real dynamic language, and want to use Parrot for its continuations and other dynamic features, see the O'Reilly Books ***Perl and Parrot Essentials*** (there are several editions), the chapters on PIR/IMCC are about my stuff, and are useful. If your language isn't dynamic, then stay far away from Parrot.

If you are bent on writing your own VM, let me suggest you prototype the VM in Perl, Python or Ruby. I have done this a couple of times with success. It allows you to avoid too much implementation early, until your language starts to mature. Perl+Regex are easy to tweak. An intermediate language assembler in Perl or Python takes a few days to write. Later, you can rewrite the 2nd version in C++ if you still feel like it.

All this I can sum up with: avoid premature optimizations, and avoid trying to do everything at once.

Comment: LLVM is also an interesting back end.

Comment: Agree. I don't dissuade him from learning it, just to postpone it. +1

Comment: I'm not so sure that using a LALR parser generator is the best option for getting started. I know (from myself and others) that creating a LALR grammar is much pain for little benefit. Not only do you have to remove shift/reduce conflicts, but *how* to do this is not intuitive for beginners. Sure, you gain benefits, for example you're forced to resolve ambiguities, but that is exactly the kind of thing that can safely be ignored at the start. I think PEGs or (my favorite) Pratt parsers are easier to deal with and more intuitive for programmers (as opposed to automata theorists).

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get a good book. So I refer you to the book by John Gough in my other answer, but emphasize, focus on learning to implement an AST for a single, existing platform first. It will help you learn about AST implementation.

**How to implement a loop?**

Your language parser should return a tree node during the reduce step for the WHILE statement. You might name your AST class WhileStatement, and the WhileStatement has, as members, ConditionExpression and BlockStatement and several labels (also inheritable but I added inline for clarity).

Grammar pseudocode below, shows the how the reduce creates a new object of WhileStatement from a typical shift-reduce parser reduction.

**How does a shift-reduce parser work?**

```
WHILE ( ConditionExpression )
    BlockStatement
    {
       $$ = new WhileStatement($3, $5);
       statementList.Add($$); // this is your statement list (AST nodes), not the parse stack
    }
 ;
```

As your parser sees "WHILE", it shifts the token on the stack. And so forth.

```
parseStack.push(WHILE);
parseStack.push('(');
parseStack.push(ConditionalExpression);
parseStack.push(')');
parseStack.push(BlockStatement);
```

The instance of WhileStatement is a node in a linear statement list. So behind the scenes, the "$$ =" represents a parse reduce (though if you want to be pedantic, $$ = ... is user-code, and the parser is doing its own reductions implicitly, regardless). The reduce can be thought of as popping off the tokens on the right side of the production, and replacing with the single token on the left side, reducing the stack:

```
// shift-reduce
parseStack.pop_n(5);         // pop off the top 5 tokens ($1 = WHILE, $2 = (, $3 = ConditionExpression, etc.)
parseStack.push(currToken);  // replace with the current $$ token
```

You still need to add your own code to add statements to a linked list, with something like "statements.add(whileStatement)" so you can traverse this later. The parser has no such data structure, and its stacks are only transient.

During parse, synthesize a WhileStatement instance with its appropriate members.
In latter phase, implement the visitor pattern to visit each statement and resolve symbols and generate code. So a while loop might be implemented with the following AST C++ class:

```
class WhileStatement : public CompoundStatement {
    public:
        ConditionExpression * condExpression;  // this is the conditional check

        Label               * startLabel;      // Label can simply be a Symbol
        Label               * redoLabel;       // Label can simply be a Symbol
        Label               * endLabel;        // Label can simply be a Symbol
        BlockStatement      * loopStatement;  // this is the loop code

        bool ResolveSymbolsAndTypes();
        bool SemanticCheck();
        bool Emit();         // emit code
}
```

Your code generator needs to have a function that generates sequential labels for your assembler. A simple implementation is a function to return a string with a static int that increments, and returns LBL1, LBL2, LBL3, etc. Your labels can be symbols, or you might get fancy with a Label class, and use a constructor for new Labels:

```
class Label : public Symbol {
   public Label() {
      this.name = newLabel();  // incrementing LBL1, LBL2, LBL3
   }
}
```

A loop is implemented by generating the code for condExpression, then the redoLabel, then the blockStatement, and at the end of blockStatement, then goto to redoLabel.

A sample from one of my compilers to generate code for the CLR.

```
 // Generate code for .NET CLR for While statement
 //
 void WhileStatement::clr_emit(AST *ctx)
 {
    redoLabel = compiler->mkLabelSym();
    startLabel = compiler->mkLabelSym();
    endLabel = compiler->mkLabelSym();

    // Emit the redo label which is the beginning of each loop
    compiler->out("%s:\n", redoLabel->getName());
    if(condExpr) {
       condExpr->clr_emit_handle();
       condExpr->clr_emit_fetch(this, t_bool);
       // Test the condition, if false, branch to endLabel, else fall through
       compiler->out("brfalse %s\n", endLabel->getName());
    }

    // The body of the loop
    compiler->out("%s:\n", startLabel->getName());   // start label only for clarity

    loopStmt->clr_emit(this);                        // generate code for the block

    // End label, jump out of loop
    compiler->out("br %s\n", redoLabel->getName());   // goto redoLabel
    compiler->out("%s:\n", endLabel->getName());      // endLabel for goto out of loop
 }
```

Comment: I'm sorry but you cannot possibly describe `$$ = ` as a 'parse reduce'. The reduction is already happening: this is why the user code is being executed. User code such as an assignment to `$$` is just a semantic action, not a parser action. The generated parser does all the shifting and reducing, not the user code.

Comment: "cannot possibly" is a strong term. I'm trying to explain it in as simple terms to a beginner as possible. You are taking a small piece of my post of out context. I said "behind the scenes", and in language I hope he can relate to.